# Product view does not inherit default head block xml (Magento 2 CE)

Tags: magento2, magento-community, frontend

First off let me just say, I am green when it comes to Magento (all versions) and have been trying to figure this out for two days and I am not sure what else to try. I have been fiddling with a custom template that inherits the *Luma theme* and I have figured out how to muddle through the `xml` files for block placements and so forth, mostly getting things to work by trial and error. I changed the `default_head_blocks.xml` located in my custom theme here:

```
/app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

to include a custom css file to override some of the *Luma* css (mine is labelled as `css/mycss.css`):

```
<head>
    <meta name="x_ua_compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    <css src="css/mycss.css"/><!-- <<<--- I added this -->
    <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
</head>
```

I was very happy with myself that something I did actually worked, until I went to look at the single product view *(the category view inherits the css just fine and I also have the category set to apply my template to in-category products...something else I tried, not sure if that is right or not)*. I checked to make sure the product itself was also using my template under the `Design` tab in the admin area, which it says it is. Then I went to the catalog folder to try and mess around with all of the xml documents pertaining to product such as the `catalog_product_view.xml`, `catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`, etc... and adding:

```
<head>
    <css src="css/mycss.css"/>
</head>
```

I should mention I did move all combinations of these xml files into both:

```
/app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/
```

and/or

```
/app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/Magento_Theme/layout/
```

Last thing to mention, I flush my cache every time I change something.

Anyway, I have Googled the crap out of this and I tried to adapt some Magento 1.x answers to try and solve it, but I can not figure it out with my limited Magento knowledge. Any push in the right direction would be helpful at this point because I am just staring at my Magento project folder right now with a dumb perplexed look on my face...

---

**EDIT**

After more "trial and error" I have deduced that this page, including the account signup, login, etc. are just using the `base` template...how do I know? I did the unthinkable! Just to test, I added my `<css src="css/mycss.css"/>` to the base theme's `default_head_blocks.xml` file located here:

```
/vendors/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

So I guess my question is, how come it's using the `base` template *(which I already suspected it was doing)* and not the one I am assigning it? I am missing something, but I don't know what it is or where to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out this issue, the only option I had left was to delete the *"working"* installation of Magento2 and reinstall it (I actually reinstalled it 4 times)...basically I started over and went through all the set-up again. I resolved the issue in developer mode, but I have not tried it in production mode. I don't really know if it was a permissions thing, or some cache thing, or what...but reinstalling fixed it.

The solution is not an ideal one.

Answer (score 0):

For adding custom or as you say "mycss.css" in your theme layout
you have to place "mycss.less" file in to 
app\design\frontend\Zenon\zenon\Magento_Theme\web\css\mycss.less

after that change the css debugging mode to public or client side.

after than do static content deploy using compressor

Comment: Hello thank you for your interest. Let me clarify a bit, I have no issues getting CSS working in everything except the single product view, account signup, login etc. The problem is not the CSS, that is a symptom of the problem. The real problem is that I have told Magento to use my template for the product(s) in the admin, but it's still using the `base` template. I can live with the other parts not looking like the rest of the site, I can fiddle with that later, but I need the product page(s) to inherit my template.